# google script editor error "logger" not defined

Tags: logging, google-apps-script

I am working on a simple example to prove the logger is working on my google script editor. but i get the error "logger" is not defined.
i assume the logger function should work with out adding any libraries.

this is the code:

```
function myFunction() {
var a = [];
for (var i=0; i<5; ++i) {
a.push(i);
}
logger.log(a);
}
```

please let me know if i need to set any libraries or permissions.

thanks. 
[here you can see the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/di61f.png)

[this is the text from the logger.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jmji.png)

Comment: You need to define/import the log API in your code.

Comment: Logger not logger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works: Just Capitalize Logger.

```
function myOne() {
var a = [];
for (var i=0; i<5; ++i) {
a.push(i);
}
Logger.log(a);
}
```